# system.uri' does not contain a definition for 'parsequerystring'

Tags: c#, .net, uri

Following an online guide for building a C# class, and pasting the class code into a new class, the only part that doesn't resolve is this line:

```
        canonicalRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", GetCanonicalQueryParameters(request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()));
```

From this function

```
    private static string GetCanonicalRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, string[] signedHeaders)
    {
        var canonicalRequest = new StringBuilder();
        canonicalRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", request.Method.Method);
        canonicalRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath);
        canonicalRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", GetCanonicalQueryParameters(request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()));
        canonicalRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", GetCanonicalHeaders(request, signedHeaders));
        canonicalRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", String.Join(";", signedHeaders));
        canonicalRequest.Append(GetPayloadHash(request));
        return canonicalRequest.ToString();
    }
```

The error is that System.Uri doesn't contain a definition for parsequerystring? This seems odd, as MSDN reveals this is a legitimate function that is used to get the query part of a URL. I have all the required usings and references, but this still won't resolve. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` library (right click on References, then select "Add Reference", browse the .NET references for that library.

Then be sure to add the correct "using" at the top:

`using System.Net.Http`

The method is an extension method, and the documentation can be [found here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.uriextensions.parsequerystring(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: All I can find is System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.WebRequest (and I have added references via that method before, so I'm sure I'm doing the right thing, but it's just not there :/ I'm using Framework 4.5.2 by the way....

Comment: Solved - needed to use Nuget, and a VERY specific version of the assembly, any other version produces a failed constraint against another assembly, but this one works OK PM> Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting -Version 4.0.20505